# Jquery select with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dynamic, plugins

I am using the jquery select2 plugin, this was my first select:

```
$('#dropdown_users').select2({
        placeholder: 'Search for a category', 
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "search.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    term: term, //search term
                    page_limit: 20 // page size
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return { results: data.results };
            }
        }

});
```

This works perfect, the text is displayed.

Not i wanted to add an image to the displayed text, what i did:

```
function format(state) {
        if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
        return "<img class='flag' src='uploads/" + state.text.toLowerCase() + ".jpg'/>";
}
$('#dropdown_users').select2({
        placeholder: 'Search for a category', 
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "search.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    term: term, //search term
                    page_limit: 20 // page size
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return { results: data.results };
            }
        },
        formatResult: format,
        formatSelection: format,
        escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }

});
```

What is happening:

1. The image is displayed correctly.
2. The text next to the image disappear´s.

Why? Anybody could help me with this problem?? Greetings!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `state.text` along with the return of the image from the format function:

```
return '<img class="flag" src="uploads/' + state.text.toLowerCase() + '.jpg" />' + state.text;
```

For my reference, see: [Select 2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#templating).

Answer (score 0):

increase the width of the select using css.

```
#dropdown_users{
 width:300px !important;//some width which suits the size of the image and text
 //float:left;

}
```

you can also add float left for both image and the text by adding the span or Div wrapper to both elements.